# Querying MySQL to show number of entires and sort

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with these columns:

```
bookingdatetime (DateTime)
promo (Varchar)
```

I want to query the database to count the number of different promo codes used (if the promo row isn't blank) and give an output like this:

```
promo               amount appeared that month    
example - 01/20     13

<promocode - mm/yy> <number of times that code was used in that month>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, '%m/%y') `promo`, 
       SUM(promo != '') 'count'
FROM `reservations`
WHERE pickuploc = 'la'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, '%m/%y'), YEAR(bookingdatetime)
ORDER BY YEAR(bookingdatetime), DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, '%m/%y')
```

I need to get the promo code used in promo before the %m%y and I need to not show if count has 0 entires.

Comment: Have you tried out count(promo)? count only counts NOT NULL values. Keep your blank promos as NULL values.

Comment: check updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```sql
SELECT
  CONCAT(promo, ' - ', DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, '%m/%y')) AS promo,
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM reservations
WHERE pickuploc = 'la'
  AND COALESCE(promo, '') <> ''
GROUP BY
  DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, '%m/%y'),
  promo
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
ORDER BY
  DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, '%y'),
  DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, '%m')
```

Sample Output:

```
promo         count
foo - 01/19   2
bar - 01/19   1
foo - 02/19   2
bar - 03/19   1
foo - 03/19   1
```

SQL Fiddle Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86083/5